# Pronunciation of “и” at end for these specific words

Tags: словоупотребление

In words such as `по-дружески` or `по-человечески`:

I have looked through dictionaries and cannot find why 
in these words the «и» at the end sounds like the letter e=ye. Why is that, what is the rule?

Comment: if you speak of the Russian E and NOT English E, then it absolutely does not sound like E, at the very least it should not, it's difficult to offer any other suggestion until you provide audio where you think it's pronounced like E, if it's on Babbel and inaccessible to unregistered visitors, you may record it, upload onto another file locker and post a link

Comment: Similar question: https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/14781/2104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds of a language are a fuzzy concept and when it comes to mapping them to letters, a lot depends on the listener's background. Many things only exist in the eye of the beholder (or the ear of the listener).

Many Russian speakers heard the English refrain "She's got it" as "Shizgara" ([«Шизгара»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus)) with the original 't' mapped to 'r' and the weak 'it' to weak 'a'.

I suggest that you just assume that there is an И at the end of these words and continue to practise listening until you 'get it'.

Comment: an even more peculiar case of distortion is the word эщкере, which is the English "Let's get it"

Comment: Both examples map the intervocal -t- to -r- and 'it' to a schwa. So there's a system there!